# How can I write a function to be called twice, with arrays of different lengths as arguments, that correctly returns expected output array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to refactor a function I wrote that needs to produce two different arrays, rendered as headings for separate columns on a page. The first run through I ended up with two different functions two produce the two different headings, which seems silly. The refactor has gotten me as far as one function to produce both. But that one function has to be called/instantiated twice, once passing in an array of strings of length 3 and then again passing in an array of strings of length 4.

The result for each call should be a new, separate, correctly joined array depending on an `if` statement that checks four different boolean values. Part of the problem is that two of the boolean values share the same string if `true`, which is why the arrays being passed into the function are different lengths.

An example return would be that, if a user has access to the "Syndicate" source and the "Facebook" source I would expect two separate headings rendered to the page like so:

"Series, Sports, Pages" and "Airings, Posts"

If a user had access to all sources, the expected arrays/headings would be:

"Series, Sports, Pages, Channels, Playlists" and "Airings, Posts, Media, Videos"

How could I refactor this to return the desired arrays for the two different calls?

```
getColumnLabels = (array) => {
  let labelArr = [];
  if (this.state.source.Syndicate) { labelArr.push(array[0]) }
  if (this.state.source.Facebook || this.state.source.Instagram) { labelArr.push(array[1]) }
  if (this.state.source.YouTube) { labelArr.push(array[2]) }
  return labelArr.join(', ');
}

this.getColumnLabels(["Series, Sports", "Pages", "Channels, Playlists"])
this.getColumnLabels(["Airings", "Posts", "Media", "Videos"])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to return two data structures from a function. you could return a single structure that has the separate arrays you need.

`{headingOne: [].join(', '), headingTwo: [].join(', ')}`

I dont really get the logic you're trying to build.
could you comment this with a pseudocode?